# how to convert a simple python code weekday check

Tags: python, weekday

Okay, i wrote this code myself awhile ago

but now im having trouble conerting it so it only does this years dates, ie the user would only have to type MM-DD instead of YYYY-MM-DD because we are going to assume its 2011

Comment: FWIW, you might want to assume it's the current year rather than hardcoding 2011. You might even want to check if that assumption leads to something in the past and, if so, assume the following year instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime
def weekday(dateinput):
    a = dateinput.split("-")
    b = datetime.date(datetime.date.today().year, int(a[0]), int(a[1]))
    c = b.strftime("%A")
    return c
#- test harness: do not modify -#
dateinput = raw_input('Enter a date ("MM-DD"): ')
print "That's a " + weekday(dateinput) + '.'
```

If you actually want to assume 2011 even in 2012, replace `datetime.date.today().year` with the hard-coded year.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
def weekday(dateinput):
    dateinput = "2011-" + dateinput
    a = dateinput.split("-")
    b = datetime.date(int(a[0]), int(a[1]), int(a[2]))
    c = b.strftime("%A")
    return c

print weekday("03-15")
```

prints `Tuesday`

Comment: Hard coding the current year is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I know it but I did't want to change his program. Eventually it was his work. I just added the year he wanted. We wanted 2011.